# Регулярное выражение шаблон для Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Есть очень много текста с цифрами, пример:

```
 стежки фурнитура      1 083 056   
 фурнитура женская   933 181   
 шлевки  621 964   
 фурнитура черная мужская   923 194   
 фурнитура люкс 921 934   
 фурнитура зеленая детская         169
```

Требуется удалить ВСЕ цифры, чтобы остался только текст и чтобы, после текста не оставался пробел. Хочу заметить (если это важно) что после текста "пробелов" перед цифрами, разное количество.

Answer (score 5):

Любое количество в любых сочетаниях из пробелов и цифр до конца строки:

```
[\s\d]+$
```

Заменить на пустую строку